# Term for injective/one-to-one with respect to just one of multiple variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, notation, terminology, inverse

As I understand it , a function $z=f(x,y)$ would be one-to-one or injective if there is only one unique $(x_1,y_1)$ pair which yields some value $f(x_1,y_1)=z_1$.
In this definition, the *pair of variables* $(x,y)$ is the entity that maps one-to-one to $z$.

**Is there a "partial" equivalent to this that treats $x$ and $y$ separately?**

I want to say something like "$z=f(x,y)$ is one-to-one with respect to $x$ for all $y$" , meaning that for any choice of $y_1$ in the domain of $y$, $f(x,y_1)$ maps $x$ to $z$ one-to-one. This property would mean that I can always "invert" a function $z=f(x,y)$ into $x=f'(z,y)$, but I can't necessarily do the same for $y=f''(x,z)$.

In general , for a multi-variable function , replace "$y$" with "all other variables."

Is there a concise terminology for this?

Comment: I'd say something like, for each $y=y_0$, $f(x,y_0)$ is injective as a function of $x$".  Or do you mean something stronger, like "$f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)\implies x_1=x_2$"?  For instance, $f(x,y)=x$ is injective in my first sense, but not in my second.  I believe you intend the first, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You can say that $f$ is injective in the first variable, uniformly over the remaining variable(s)

Comment: I guess you may fix $y$ and let $g(x) = f(x,y)$ then say something on the injectivity of $g$

Answer (score 1):

There is no well-known standard way to state that.

(1) I would state it in 2 ways , like this :

We have a function $y=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n)$ where **there is a one-to-one correspondence between $y$ & $x_1$** , that is :
When all other variables are held constant , **$y$ & $x_1$ are invertible**.

Example :

$z=x(w^2+y^3+y^w)$
$x=z/(w^2+y^3+y^w)$

Here "$x$ & $z$ are invertible" & "there is a one-to-one correspondence between $x$ & $z$".

In that way , it is not necessary to limit it to variables : We can extend to expressions too , like this :

$Z=Y^W\sin(X)$
$\sin(X)=Z/Y^W$

Here "$\sin(X)$ & $Z$ are invertible" & "there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\sin(X)$ & $Z$".

(2) I have two more ways (without talking about inverse & injectivity) :

The third alternate way would be to simply state it like this :
While $z$ can be **explicitly evaluated** with all the other variables , $x$ too can be explicitly evaluated with all the other variables.

The fourth alternate way : I might state that when given $z=f(x,y,w)$ , $z$ is already **isolated** to one side , while $x$ too can be similarly isolated to one side.

These four ways are not widely used , though these are suitable to cover OP Case.

It is worth high-lighting that there is no well-known standard way to state what OP is looking for.